# Java. Instance variable value access via this operator

Tags: java

i need someone help with this little code snippet; why is the output: b 3 and not b 13 as expected?

```
public class Foo{ 
    int a = 3;
    public void addFive() { a+=5; System.out.println("f");}  
}

class Bar extends Foo{
int a = 8;
public void addFive() { this.a+=5; System.out.println("b");}  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f = new Bar();
    f.addFive();
    System.out.println(f.a);// why b 3 and not b 13 ??
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find a lot of this in Java Puzzlers, by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Foo` and `Bar` have two **different** `a` fields; Java does not have any notion of field overriding.

Calling `f.addFive()` calls the derived version of the method (since Java does do method overriding), which modifies `Bar.a`.
However, accessing `f.a` returns `Foo.a` (since `f` is declared as `Foo`), which was never changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually two variables called `a`: One in `Foo` and one in `Bar`.

In `Bar.addFive` you are modifying the variable `a` which is declared in `Bar` (not the one declared in `Foo`).

In addition, as variables do not show polymorphic behavior, you are accessing the variable `a` declared in `Foo` in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying `a` in `Bar` which is not the same as `a` in `Foo`, and your code is printing `a` of `Foo`

Here are some more code examples which might make you understand whats going on

```
    Foo f = new Bar();
    f.addFive();
    System.out.println(f.a);//3
    System.out.println(((Bar)f).a);//13

    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.addFive();
    System.out.println(b.a);//13
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have dynamic binding for variable instances but just on methods. When you access a field, the most specialized one (in case of name clash, like in your example) is not chosen.

The chosen one will be the one for which the variable has been declared, not the runtime one. To have dynamic bimding you shoul use a getter and not reference direcly to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

*The rules are simple.*

Polymorphism does not apply to:

1. static methods
2. private methods.
3. variables.
4. overloaded methods.
5. Generics

All the above happens in Compile time and is called Compile time binding or static binding

Dynamic Binding or Runtime binding is done in Method Overriding.

Answer (score 0):

I got ya, first of all there is overriding in JAVA. However, What you are doing is not methods overriding if you do this it will work as you want:

```
public class Foo{ 
int a = 3;
public void addFive() { a+=5; System.out.println("f");}
public int getA() {return a;}       
}

class Bar extends Foo{
int a = 8;
public void addFive() { this.a+=5; System.out.println("b");}
public int getA() {return a;}
}
```

I hope you get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo f = new Bar();
f.addFive();
```

f.addFive() executes the overriden method of Bar class. In the next line

System.out.println(f.a);

This retrieves the variable a of Foo class, which is 3 (as it is not changed).
So you got 3 as answer.